# How to have all html elements the same width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to create a webpage. The problem is that I have a horizontal navbar a main tag and a footer. When I resize the screen, the navbar main and footer do not align, the navbar is wider than the main content, and the footer is more inside. To partially fix this I modify the style of each element, but when the navbar adjusts itself, it becomes wider than other elements in the HTML. Is there a global way to make everything align?

Comment: Please add you current relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you didn't include the `collapse` class of bootstrap which help to resize the navigation bar when screen is resized.Better to use a button which on clicking shows other tags in your navigation bar which is by the way vertical for small screens.
Also please share your code so you can be helped better.

Comment: The navbar resizes, but it shrinks too much (the menu items goes on 2 lines), and then it gets again wider than the other contet, I'm looking to upload some code, but I have to edit it a lot since there is some info that I cannot post it yet online.

Comment: We only need a minimum amount of  code,just give a gest of yr code